# Javascript, splice delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working in a code that it has this:

```
let someArray = ["a","b","c"];
someArray.splice(0, someArray.length);
```

I have this test: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/sk6f7wg3/

The full code that uses that code has a strange behaviour. It's a big React component where the code is inside an await function, when I put console logs to see what have `someArray.splice(0, someArray.length);` like in the test, I can see the full array and/or the empty array. I not sure why the code is trying those splice (in many parts of the full code), maybe is trying to "reset" the array to empty? wuld be better to just redefine like

```
someArray = [];
```

Instead those `splice` ? I put the "reactjs" tag on the question because the code is in a React app that use await, and manye `this.setState` that changes the DOM, so maybe the `splice` could be a no so good options of what the coder is trying to do here.

EDIT:

Actually the component does this:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
    someArray.splice(0, sendComponents.length);
};

componentDidUpdate() {
    someArray.splice(0, sendComponents.length);
};
```

Why is trying those splices? What would be the idea? To me is trying to do

```
someArray = []
```

isn't the same?

Comment: Yes, by `someArray.splice(0, someArray.length);` you are clearing your array. Read how it works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). You can redefine it as you said `someArray = []`, but as I remember declaration of array like that can be deprecated in ESLint's rule, maybe for that reason in your code used another method to clear out an array.

Comment: Thanks. When I test with just someArray = [] seems (I dont know how to say it), faster, or inmediatly way to reset the array, in the console.logs the expeted result (empty arrays) is shown inmediatly.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is about setting a local variable to a new value, or modifying an existing array, so the modification will be visible at its source too:

```js
function thing1(arr){
  console.log("arr in thing1 at the start:",arr.join());
  arr=[];
  console.log("arr in thing1 at the end:",arr.join());
}
function thing2(arr){
  console.log("arr in thing2 at the start:",arr.join());
  arr.splice(0,arr.length);
  console.log("arr in thing2 at the end:",arr.join());
}
let test=[1,2,3];
console.log("test before thing1:",test.join());
thing1(test);
console.log("test between thing1 and thing2:",test.join());
thing2(test);
console.log("test after thing2:",test.join());
```